# Make recycle bin appear empty in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, appearance

I prefer the appearance of the empty recycle bin to the appearnce of the non-empty recycle bin in Windows 7. In reality, the empty/not empty indicator is about useless (at least for my purposes). Thus,

**How can I track the OS into always displaying the empty version of the recycle bin?**

Comment: Don't delete anything? Don't use the Recycle Bin?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/change-how-the-recycle-bin-looks)

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath Yes, I'm looking to make the recycle bin always invisible. However, I am using the l̶a̶t̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ greatest OS: Windows 7.

Comment: It's exactly the same process in Windows 7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Personalization

Select 'Change Desktop Icons'.

Select 'Recycle Bin (full)', click 'Change Icon' and choose the empty recycle bin icon for when it is full if that is what you're wanting.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much :)